# How to import a python file that is in the same directory as the file I am trying to run from outside of that directory?

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

`PS C:\Users\arkad\Documents\repos\backpack-calculator> python C:\Users\arkad\Documents\repos\backpack-calculator\src\main.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\arkad\Documents\repos\backpack-calculator\src\main.py", line 3, in <module>     from src.main_window import MainWindow ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

It seems I don't know how to properly import python modules in a relativistic way. How do people do it?

I tried changing all my import statements to exclude src directory, except for files in other test directory. This fixed the issue and allowed me to run main.py but then I would not be able to run my tests by running pytest command

[Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path) this does not answer my question. In this case person is trying to import a file that is in a different directory while I am trying to import from same directory.

Minimal example:

a src directory containing main.py and main_window.py
trying to run main.py from outside of src directory with command `python .\src\main.py`
main.py:

```
from src.main_window import MainWindow

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
```

main_window.py:

```
class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        print('test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running up against how python figures out where to import modules from.

When you run `python main.py`, python will look in the current directory to find `main.py` and then also look in the current directory for imported modules. However, when you do `python path\to\main.py` or when using an absolute path things start to work a little differently. Python will still try to find your file from the current directory (if given a relative path). But instead of looking in the current directory for imported modules it will look in the directory that contains your main file. So `C:\path\to` in my example or `C:\Users\arkad\Documents\repos\backpack-calculator\src` in yours. So you can see it won't find a module called `src.main_window`. You can find more about how python decides where to look for modules in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

There are a number of different solutions you can try.

## Use PYTHONPATH

You can tell python where to look for your other modules by setting an environment variable called `PYTHONPATH`. I believe in PowerShell the syntax to do this would be:

```
Set-Item -Path env:PYTHONPATH -Value 'C:\Users\arkad\Documents\repos\backpack-calculator'
python C:\Users\arkad\Documents\repos\backpack-calculator\src\main.py
```

## Use the `-m` command line option

By using `-m` we are telling python the name of the module (rather than file) we want it to find from the current directory. For example:

```
cd C:\Users\arkad\Documents\repos\backpack-calculator
python -m src.main # src\main.py -> src.main
```

## Use a shim main script

Create a file in the folder containing the `src` directory and make it import your main script and call its entry function.

```py
# newmain.py
from src.main import main  # assuming you have a function called main
main()
```

```
cd C:\Users\arkad\Documents\repos\backpack-calculator
python newmain.py
```

## Change your imports

Since you know that if you run `python C:\path\to\src\main.py`, that python will look for modules in `C:\path\to\src`, then you do not need to do `from src.foo import bar`. You can instead do `from foo import bar`.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. May I also ask how you know this? Or rather do you have a source of this information? What did you use to learn this?

Comment: Here's the docs how python searches for modules: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

1. this folder structure:

```bash
└───backpack
    └───src
            main.py
            x.py
```

2. Your working directory is .../backpack>
3. You run python src/main.py

Then python will search for imports (I'm simplifying a lot here) in 2 places:

- in your installed packages path
- in the directory of the .py file you run (so, inside src/)

So you can import x.py from main.py with:

```
import x
```

If you want this to work though:

```
import src.x
```

Then you would have to put x in src folder:

```bash
└───backpack
    └───src
        │   main.py
        │
        └───src
                x.py
```

Or you would have to make python look for packages from a 3rd place - from your working directory.
You can do that by running main.py as a module:

```
python -m src.main
```

More common practice for src layout repositories though is to run pytest as a module instead:

```
python -m pytest
```

This will enable pytest to import stuff from your working directory :)

For more pytest src layout nice practices see:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html